# Set minimal time for ProgressDialog , maximum not need

Tags: android

I need to display user info while app processing some data. I use ProgressDialog like

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                        "", "Processing",
                        true, false);
```

Processing takes while connect to network and download data, but when network is not available it returns immediately and my progress dialog just flash very quick. Is there maybe more elegant solution then  to put in catch Thread to sleep for some time :

```
try{
  //connecting and calculating
}
catch(Exception exc){
Thread.sleep(400);
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

I need to set minimal time for my ProgressDialog regardless of success or failure ? Does anybody know how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

Write the following code immediately after the dialog initialization

```
new Thread(){
public void run(){
try{
Thread.sleep(5000); 
}
catch(Exception ex){}
try{
Message msg=actHandler.obtainMessage();
actHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
catch(NullPointerException ex){
Log.e("Handler Exception :",ex.toString());
dialog.dismiss();
}
}
}.start();


actHandler=new Handler(){
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
super.handleMessage(msg);
doSomthing();
}
};


public void doSomething(){
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the other way around: only show your progressDialog *if* you can establish the connexion. I feel that making the user wait 0.4 second for a result you already know just for the bling is pointless ;)